# Find the first term and the common ratio of an infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

> Find the first term and the common ratio of an infinite geometric series whose sum is $5$ and such that each term is $4$ times the sum of all the terms that follow it.

I used $a_{1}r^{3}=\frac{4[a_{1}(r^{3}-1)]}{r-1}$ infinite geometric series. Solving that I got the value of $r= -0.83$. Substituting to the formula of infinite GS, I have my $a_1= 9.15$. many thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your attempts where you got stuck ?which formulas you used? so that we can help you

Comment: Hi everyone, I used a_1r^3= (4a_1(r^3-1)/(r-1). I used the nth term formula of the geometric sequence and the formula of the infinite geometric series. Solving that I got the value of r= -0.83. Substituting to the formula of infinite GS,  I have my a_1= 9.15. many thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkLarson Note that the sum of all terms after $a_1$ is equal to $a_1/4$, so the sum of the entire series is $5a_1/4 = 5$.  The first term practically solves for itself :)

Comment: @MarkLarson Can you explain where the exponent $3$ in $r^3$ comes from?  I interpret the question to mean “all of the (infinitely many) terms that follow it”, not “the 2 or 3 terms that follow it”.

Comment: @Erick Wong I think I interpret the question the other way around but I got your point:)

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{a_1}{1-r}=5$$ and $$a_n=\frac{4a_{n+1}}{1-r}.$$
The second gives $$1=\frac{4r}{1-r}$$ or $$r=\frac{1}{5},$$ which gives $$\frac{a_1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}=5$$ and $$a_1=4$$